# White-space property for Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've been trying to find the bootstrap equivalent of the CSS property `"white-space: break-spaces"` but I can't seem to find one.

My problem is that in the mobile view of my screen, the button goes out of the view since the text in it is long.

This is my button

```
<button class="btn btn-primary mt-3" id="send_sms_btn" type="submit">Verify &amp; Submit Withdrawal</button>
```

CSS property applied to the element works fine but I can only use bootstrap.
Any suggestions?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/text/#word-break

check this link

Comment: Ahhh, yes! It works. Using the class "text-wrap". You can answer the question and I'll up-vote.
Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding the `.text-break` class to the button

```
<button class="btn btn-primary mt-3 text-break" id="send_sms_btn" type="submit">Verify &amp; Submit Withdrawal</button>
```

[Text break reference Link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/text/#word-break)

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>    
button.overflow {
          white-space: nowrap; 
          width: 100%; 
          overflow: hidden;
          text-overflow: ellipsis; 
          border: 1px solid #000000;
}
</style>
```

Add this style in `css` file or `head` tag.

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary mt-3 overflow" id="send_sms_btn" type="submit">Verify &amp; Submit too too long long long long long text</button>
```

> use `overflow` class in button. It will not go out of the screen.
> Let's try. Hope will solve issue.

Comment: CSS will work but I can only use default bootstrap classes.

Comment: OP clearly said that they need the bootstrap class for this